# Non-resolvable parent POM in Maven Project made with http://start.spring.io/

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I've created a Maven Project using Spring Initializr, but when I try to build it I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/alessandro/Work/workspaces/demo/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.2.RELEASE from/to repo (http://artifactory.dev.*****.it/artifactory/repo): Failed to transfer http://artifactory.dev.*****.it/artifactory/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.2.RELEASE.pom. Error code 504, Gateway Time-out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

the auto-generated pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I tried to specify a relative path inside the *parent* tag (like '../pom.xml') without success, can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: "Error code 504, Gateway Time-out". So you have internet connection issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with start.spring.io.

You most probably have a custom `~/.m2/settings.xml` where everything (or Maven Central) is proxied to http://artifactory.dev.*****.it/artifactory/repo/

> Failed to transfer http://artifactory.dev.*****.it/artifactory/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.2.RELEASE.pom.

If that artifactory server is supposed to fetch outside, maybe there's a network glitch or something. Regardless, please ask the admin of that server for help.

Comment: I've removed that file and it works fine. Thank you.